# How to get the last execution in a PHP for loop

Tags: php

I am trying to get the last code execution in a basic `PHP` `forloop`. Currently I have been able to execute `n-1` times and statically written the code for `n=n` outside the loop. This concept will fail if `n = 1` unless I use an `if-statement` outside the loop. Is there a way I can get the last execution inside the loop?

```
<?php 

$total_time_months = 6;

$time_now = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

for ($x = 1; $x <= $total_time_months-1; $x++) {
       $offset = strtotime('+'. $x .' months');
       echo $next_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $offset)."<br>"; // this is the n-1 time
}

//do something statically knowing that there is suposed to be one more left
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('+'. $total_time_months. ' months'))."<br>";

?>
```

For this question, `n = $total_time_months`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all. Instead of using `x <= y - 1` you can always simplify this to `x < y' when using a for loop.

Inside the loop you can check your current `$x`. For the last item it would be the maximum of your loop counter - 1.

Answer (score 1):

You are already using the variable `$x` for your iterations. Just check the value of `$x` inside your loop:

```
if ($x === $total_time_months-1) { 
    // ... do something
}
```

Comment: please why `$total_time_months-2`?

Comment: Since the loop begins with 1 and ends with 5, it would suggest using $x === $total_time_months-1

Comment: Sorry, you are correct, it should be `$total_time_months-1`.